# Too many return values - golang

Tags: golang

Eu tenho o seguinte arquivo de conexão com o banco:

```
package banco

import (
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" // Driver de conexão com o MySQL
)

//Abre a conexão com o banco de dados
func Conectar(*sql.DB, error) {
    stringConexao := "#####:#####@/######?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"

    db, erro := sql.Open("mysql", stringConexao)
    if erro != nil {
        return nil, erro
    }

    if erro = db.Ping(); erro != nil {
        return nil, erro
    }

    return db, nil
}
```

Porém em todos os meus returns, eu obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
too many return values
have (*sql.DB, nil)
want ()
```

Eu já chequei alguns tópicos da comunidade, mas sigo sem sucesso com esses erros.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Conectar não retorna nenhum valor e você esta retornando dois.

```
func Conectar(*sql.DB, error) { <--
        stringConexao := "#####:#####@/######?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    
        db, erro := sql.Open("mysql", stringConexao)
        if erro != nil {
            return nil, erro <--
        }
    
        if erro = db.Ping(); erro != nil {
            return nil, erro <--
        }
    
        return db, nil <--

}
```

O correto seria algo como `Conectar() (*sql.DB, error)`

De uma olhada de como se retorna mais de um valor https://gobyexample.com/multiple-return-values

Comment: Ah sim, entendi... no meu caso seria Conectar() (*sql.DB, error)... muito obrigado, deixei passar isso mesmo.